# Centering inline-block - Chrome ignore css top position after window resize, BUG?

Tags: css, google-chrome, resize, position, media-queries

I am trying to use vertical centering through http://jsfiddle.net/AqcfN/:

```
.is-verticallyCentered {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Everything is working fine until I resize Chrome window to met mediaQueries at (min-width: 500px) from higher resolution.

```
.windowOverlay_container {
    display: block;
}

@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
    .windowOverlay_container {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Parent of whiteBox is changed from inline-block to block (whiteBox is on the left then) and it is still ok (whiteBox is vertically centered) but after resize from <500px to 501px+ -> Chrome ignore "top: 50%" on the parent and whiteBox is no longer centered.

**Simply Chrome ignore top position when element changed display: block to inline-block by mediaQueries.**

---

(I don't want to use display: table/table-cell.)

(When I used only "display: inline-block" whole time, then there is no problem. - **it solved my problem on my project**)

Comment: Chrome BUG report — https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=372936

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

And add:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(25%);
-moz-transform: translateY(25%);
-ms-transform: translateY(25%);
-o-transform: translateY(25%);
transform: translateY(25%)
```

Comment: Box is not centered vertically If you set "translateY(25%)".